# How does .NET locate the dll of the namespace I'm `using`?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

How does .NET locate the dll of the namespace I'm `using`?
yeah, we do mention the path in /referene:c:\program files** but after building & deploying and when the software is installed on some user's machine. It may not be at the same path as I (developer) mentioned it would be. I mean it could be some where else right?

1. So, how does .NET find it?
2. How does .NET know at the runtime what all namespaces are there in a dll?
3. What if the user has the same dll but he renamed it? Does .net fails to load it then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the various probing steps in action if you run fuslogvw.exe (from the .NET SDK) and enable logging of all binds to disk. You will be able to see the various paths that .NET CLR uses to resolve assembly references. The rule of thumb though is to try the Global Assembly Cache first then check the local directory along with a bunch of other alternate paths.

Comment: This sounds interesting but when I started "Windows SDK tools > Fusion log viewer" every button is disabled on that window. In settings dialog also everything is disabled.

Comment: If you are using Vista or Windows 7 with UAC enabled, you should run it from an elevated command prompt because it requires administrative privileges to change the fusion logging settings.

Comment: "The rule of thumb though is to try the Global Assembly Cache first then check the local directory along with a bunch of other alternate paths."

Say If I've installed ".NET MYSQL CONNECTOR" (using MySql.Data). Using references at compile time it detects the dll but its path will be somthing like c:\programfiles\mysql\.net\mysql.dll but after the application is built and some other is using it. all my application knows is that its this mysql.dll but on the usermachine this .net connector might be installed on d:\apps\somecrap\mysql.dll. Then how could clr detect?

Comment: Cesar posted a link to the assembly probing rules. But as I stated, the CLR will first check the Global Assembly Cache, then it will look in the local directory of the application. The fact that you referenced it from an unrelated path means nothing. Visual Studio by default sets the "copy local" attribute of these references if the assembly is not in the GAC. When you compile, Visual Studio copies that DLL to the bin directory.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, there aren't any namespaces in the DLL.

On CLR level, there are no namespaces at all, only full class names. A CLR class name can consist of an arbitrarily long sequence of any Unicode characters - e.g. `@#$%` would be a perfectly fine class name, as far as CLR is concerned.

Now, *by convention* (CLS, to be specific), class names are restricted to certain Unicode characters (alphanumerics and `_`, and a bunch of other exotic Unicode categories - see the spec for more info) and dot, and dot is used to denote namespaces. This is purely a convention between *compilers* (and other tools).

So, whenever an assembly references some type for any reason, it simply uses its complete CLR name, such as `System.String`. But there is more - in fact, it uses a fully qualified name, which includes an assembly as well. You can see those if you look at `ildasm` output - they look something like `[mscorlib]System.String`, so the runtime knows where to look.

In other words, CLR really sees assembly mscorlib.dll having class `System.String`, and assembly B.exe referencing that class as `[mscorlib]System.String`. Your `using` statement doesn't generate any code in the output DLL/EXE on its own; it's there just so that you don't have to write `System.String` all the time.

It's compiler's job to translate your code saying `String`, in a scope of a `using System;` statement, in a project which references `mscorlib.dll`, to `[mscorlib]System.String`. It's all done at compile-time. The only thing CLR does at runtime is resolving `mscorlib` to locate the actual mscorlib.dll on disk (and the other answer explains how exactly that happens).

Comment: How does it resolve from System.String to [mscorlib]System.String
How does it know its in mscorlib assembly? System.String is quite common type. What about some custom 3rd party types. How will the compiler know in which assembly that class is located?

Comment: It will look inside all assemblies referenced by the project you're compiling (or specified using `/r:` on command line). If two assemblies you reference both define a class named `System.String`, you'll get a compiler error (but you can work around that in C# using `extern alias` to disambiguate assemblies).

Comment: "The only thing CLR does at runtime is resolving mscorlib to locate the actual mscorlib.dll on disk ." --- Say If I've installed ".NET MYSQL CONNECTOR" (using MySql.Data). Using references at compile time it detects the dll but its path will be somthing like c:\programfiles\mysql\.net\mysql.dll but after the application is built and some other is using it. all my application knows is that its this mysql.dll but on the usermachine this .net connector might be installed on d:\apps\somecrap\mysql.dll. Then how could it detect? this is what my original question is, If i was not clear.

Comment: [mscorlib]System.String is it sufficent? doesn't it require strong name for this? something like [mscorlib <version> <PublicKeyToken> <Culture>] System.String

Comment: You're right, it will be a strong name - in IL, other information about a referenced assembly, such as version of public key token, is specified in the assembly manifest in `.assembly extern` declaration. Regarding how it finds the assembly at run-time from a weak or strong name, Cesar's answer gives the link to the definite source on the exact rules for that. As noted by Josh, a short and simplified (and not 100% correct) answer for desktop applications is "look in GAC first, then in same directory as .exe file that started the process".

Answer (score 4):

Assembly location rules are explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The names of assemblies and namespaces are unrelated concepts.

Compiled assembly reference other assemblies by containing their [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx).

When an assembly is loaded, its references are loaded by searching for the name as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx). The most common location for assemblies are the [Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx) of a machine, and the base directory of an application.

After loading the assembly and all its references (and the references of the references, etc) the runtime loads the required types from the assemblies.

For example, if you use the type `String` as in

```
using System;

...
String x = "Hello World";
```

the C#  compiler looks up `String` and resolves it to the `System.String` type in the `mscorlib` assembly, and transforms the code to something similar to this:

```
[mscorlib]System.String x = "Hello World";
```

So when the statement is executed the runtime knows both the full name of the type `System.String` and the name of the assembly that contains the type.

Comment: Compiled assemblies can reference other assemblies by weak names, too.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer that answers the question is Pavel Minaev's comment.

Take the following basic C# Program.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler resolves `Console` by looking at all the assemblies that are referenced using `/r:` in the compilation command line. If there are more than 2 definitions of `Console` for the global namespace in the assemblies that are referenced, which is extended using the `using` statements, then there will be a compiler error -- to resolve this you would need to explicitly use `System.Console` to indicate the `System` namespace rather than the global namespace.

Similarly, if you use `System.Console`, then if there is more than one definition of `System.Console` in the assemblies that are referenced then there is a compiler error. This would either be 2 classes in the `System` namespace with the same name, which would need to be resolved by the programmer by renaming that, or defining a class called `System` in the global namespace that has been extended by `using System`, where `System.Console` is a subclass, which would be impossible to distinguish even if it were using `global::`

Once it has found a referenced assembly that contains the definition, it can now work with that definition and produce the correct IL.

When you compile this simple application, you get the following in `ildasm`:

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern /*23000001*/ mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly /*20000001*/ ConsoleApp1
{
  .custom /*0C000001:0A000001*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute/*01000001*/::.ctor(int32) /* 0A000001 */ = ( 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom /*0C000002:0A000002*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute/*01000002*/::.ctor() /* 0A000002 */ = ( 01 00 01 00 54 02 16 57 72 61 70 4E 6F 6E 45 78   // ....T..WrapNonEx
                                                                                                                                                                          63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 54 68 72 6F 77 73 01 )       // ceptionThrows.

  // --- The following custom attribute is added automatically, do not uncomment -------
  //  .custom /*0C000003:0A000003*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/*01000003*/::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/*01000003*//DebuggingModes/*01000004*/) /* 0A000003 */ = ( 01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00 ) 

  .custom /*0C000004:0A000004*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute/*01000005*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A000004 */ = ( 01 00 0B 43 6F 6E 73 6F 6C 65 41 70 70 31 00 00 ) // ...ConsoleApp1..
  .custom /*0C000005:0A000005*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute/*01000006*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A000005 */ = ( 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom /*0C000006:0A000006*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute/*01000007*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A000006 */ = ( 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom /*0C000007:0A000007*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute/*01000008*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A000007 */ = ( 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom /*0C000008:0A000008*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute/*01000009*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A000008 */ = ( 01 00 0B 43 6F 6E 73 6F 6C 65 41 70 70 31 00 00 ) // ...ConsoleApp1..
  .custom /*0C000009:0A000009*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute/*0100000A*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A000009 */ = ( 01 00 12 43 6F 70 79 72 69 67 68 74 20 C2 A9 20   // ...Copyright .. 
                                                                                                                                                               20 32 30 32 31 00 00 )                            //  2021..
  .custom /*0C00000A:0A00000A*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyTrademarkAttribute/*0100000B*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A00000A */ = ( 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom /*0C00000B:0A00000B*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute/*0100000C*/::.ctor(bool) /* 0A00000B */ = ( 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom /*0C00000C:0A00000C*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute/*0100000D*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A00000C */ = ( 01 00 24 64 66 65 35 65 36 32 61 2D 65 61 31 33   // ..$dfe5e62a-ea13
                                                                                                                                                               2D 34 66 37 64 2D 39 36 39 32 2D 37 35 39 39 64   // -4f7d-9692-7599d
                                                                                                                                                               31 31 66 31 63 36 61 00 00 )                      // 11f1c6a..
  .custom /*0C00000D:0A00000D*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute/*0100000E*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A00000D */ = ( 01 00 07 31 2E 30 2E 30 2E 30 00 00 )             // ...1.0.0.0..
  .custom /*0C00000E:0A00000E*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute/*0100000F*/::.ctor(string) /* 0A00000E */ = ( 01 00 1C 2E 4E 45 54 46 72 61 6D 65 77 6F 72 6B   // ....NETFramework
                                                                                                                                                                     2C 56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 76 34 2E 36 2E 31 01   // ,Version=v4.6.1.
                                                                                                                                                                     00 54 0E 14 46 72 61 6D 65 77 6F 72 6B 44 69 73   // .T..FrameworkDis
                                                                                                                                                                     70 6C 61 79 4E 61 6D 65 14 2E 4E 45 54 20 46 72   // playName..NET Fr
                                                                                                                                                                     61 6D 65 77 6F 72 6B 20 34 2E 36 2E 31 )          // amework 4.6.1
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}
.module ConsoleApp1.exe
// MVID: {5BC9CD36-3807-4339-8AAD-6E73A42CE87B}
.imagebase 0x00400000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00020003    //  ILONLY 32BITREQUIRED
// Image base: 0x00000000003B0000
```

```
.class /*02000002*/ private auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApp1.Program
       extends [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Object/*01000010*/
{
  .method /*06000001*/ private hidebysig static
          void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
  // SIG: 00 01 01 1D 0E
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size       13 (0xd)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
    IL_0001:  /* 72   | (70)000001       */ ldstr      "Hello" /* 70000001 */
    IL_0006:  /* 28   | (0A)00000F       */ call       void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Console/*01000011*/::WriteLine(string) /* 0A00000F */
    IL_000b:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
    IL_000c:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
  } // end of method Program::Main

  .method /*06000002*/ public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  // SIG: 20 00 01
  {
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205e
    // Code size       8 (0x8)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  /* 28   | (0A)000010       */ call       instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Object/*01000010*/::.ctor() /* 0A000010 */
    IL_0006:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
    IL_0007:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
  } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class ConsoleApp1.Program
```

As can be seen, the assembly that contains the type in a certain namespace that is being referenced is resolved by the compiler, so the runtime does not need to search the manifests of all of the dependent assemblies. Instead, looks for the assembly in the square brackets and then uses the manifest in the image that is currently running to acquire more details. It then searches the global assembly cache if it is strong named and then it searches certain directories for a `.config` file or for the assemblies themselves. On Mono, these directories are the directory that contains the image that is currently being executed on the virtual machine and the `MONO_PATH` environment variable -- it searches the GAC last.

The runtime dynamically loads assemblies when an object of type of a class in the assembly is first referenced as opposed to instantiated – the instantiation is deferred. When you use `DllImport`, the `.dll` is also dynamically loaded when it is required by the runtime. For internal calls, you would need to internally call your own native function from C# that dynamically loads a `.dll` using `LoadLibrary` and then get `GetProcAddress` to make the internal call binding, before making the real call.

An `extern alias` can be used to access an assembly that is referenced using `/r:` explicitly: `/r:GridV1=grid.dll` and then `extern alias GridV1` and then `GridV1::Namespace.Class`. The `::` operator accesses a member of an aliased namespace, which is either the `global` alias, an extern alias, or an alias created by the using alias directive. These alias directives do not extend the global namespace unlike the regular `using` or `using static`.