# How does dynamic linking work with CLR executables?

Tags: .net, windows, exe, clr

This is a theoretical question that I'm asking because I know how dynamic linking works with a regular .exe. You link the object file and the .lib and it replaces function calls with jumps to the import table and then at runtime the dynamic linker finds the module in the current directory or system32 and fills in the import table with addresses from the export table of the dll. It's roughly like that.

But with .NET, it compiles to an .exe that has I think a CLR header/CLR data at the start of the .text section and the CLR data contains CIL code. The rest of the .text section where I assume the entry point is is linked to MSCorEE.dll which probably passes a pointer to the CLR header / data to one of the MSCorEE.dll functions.

My questions is is how the CIL code of the original program gets dynamically linked with the modules that it is going to use, lets say the .NET program calls functions in kernel32.dll. If CIL is JIT compiled on the fly, how are these function calls in the CIL resolved to addresses in kernel32.dll that is loaded into the program address space? Is there a separate dynamic linker that can insert addresses of the import table functions in the CIL code before it is compiled to e.g. x86?

Comment: The pinvoke marshaler does it the exact same way that any unmanaged program will dynamically call an exported function, LoadLibrary() to load the DLL and GetProcAddress() to find the function. No linking.

Comment: This is now answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66860971/7194773). Assemblies are indicated in the CIL code in square brackets, and native .dll calls using `DllImport` attribute, the runtime will internally use `LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress`